# I can't find the proper css in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to modify the width of each column in a 2 column custom theme and can't find the place to do this. I tried using firebug but no luck. I looked over the main joomla css (didn't quite expect it to be there), and the theme template.css.

I'm sure veteran joomla programmers have ran into this plenty of times and this is an easy solve for them :P

I just need to know the places to look.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using firebug and you still can't find the path to the css file, may be you have some kind of plugin or template that packs all your style sheets into a single file?
If so, you should disable it, clear your cache, then try again with firebug, and once you find where is the css file located, enable the plugin / template feature again.
If you still can't find it, can you post the url here to take a look?

I hope it helped!

Comment: i can't tell which plugin to disable, anyway I'm sure it's not plug-in related cause we're talking about the main 2 columns of the template

Comment: Funny thing. I googled "find theme css", cause I need to modify a css again, and ended up here on my own post. Anyway, I now understand what you meant. That's exactly what's going on, it packs everything into a single file, but there is no plug-in I can disable.. or I just can't tell which one. Any other solution to this?

Comment: That was it. It turns out there was a theme css optimization feature that did exactly what you said, took all files and mixed them into one. I disabled that, now I can use firebug to see the name of the css file I need. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm glad my answer helped, even if it took almost one month :) Regards

Comment: i want style.css file path in this website http://www.choosevpn.com/ i am watching there is css path is "catalog/view/theme/vpn/stylesheet/style.css" but i can't find style.css file in there location

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's no css for this. 
Sometimes the width of columns in articles is inside de template itself like this:

```
<td valign="top" width="<?php echo intval(100 / $this->params->get('num_columns')) ?>%" class="article_column<?php echo $divider ?>">
                <?php for ($y = 0; $y < ($this->params->get('num_intro_articles') / $this->params->get('num_columns')); $y ++) :
                    if ($i < $this->total && $i < ($numIntroArticles)) :
                        $this->item =& $this->getItem($i, $this->params);
                        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                        $i ++;
                    endif;
                endfor; ?>
                </td>
```

To find something like this code look into:
template folder/ content/ com_content / the view you want to edit (i.e. : section view, category view etc)...

Also if you use Firebug or Webkit Inspector you should see the inline style as a result of this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use firebug, you should definitely see the path of the particular css. Just right-click on some column -> click on *inspect element* and then you see the css path on the right-hand side.

If your column styles are set inline, you will have to modify the right template for this. Its probably your index.php in your themes root folder or some template in the html folder.

Comment: i was using firebug, but it doesn't help much as joomla sort of collects css code from everywhere and makes a weird mix that it puts into just one temporary page... or something